# MySQL Query: How to select rows that don't have a certain value?

Tags: mysql, select

I am having trouble writing a query and I don't even know if it is possible. Take this table for example:

```
id   group  active  

1    A      NO  
2    A      YES  
3    A      NO  

4    B      YES  
5    B      NO  

6    C      NO  
7    C      NO
```

Table above is just an example. In real table there are much more columns the those tree so have that in mind. What I need is a way to select only group names that don't have any active row. In this case both "A" and "B" groups have at least one row with "active" = "YES" but if you look at C there are no active rows. The only thing I would need as a result is a group column value (in this case "C") not entire row.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT group FROM table WHERE group NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT group FROM table WHERE active = 'YES')
```

Answer (score 2):

You first want to get all the groups you wish to exclude, and then use the `NOT IN` clause to return all the other groups not in that list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.group 
FROM table t
WHERE t.group NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT t.group 
     FROM table t 
     WHERE t.active='YES');
```

Comment: This is almost like the one danben posted so I suppose it'll work too.